# Need to "Git pull" multiple times for it to work

Tags: git, git-bash

I used to use git via sourceTree but recently started using the GitBash console and I find it extremely buggy.

One thing I don't understand is why do I need to type "git pull" many times for it to actually do something?

Example

```
master$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 64, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (61/61), done.
remote: Total 64 (delta 34), reused 2 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (64/64), done. 

master$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 69, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (66/66), done.
remote: Total 69 (delta 38), reused 2 (delta 2), pack-reused 0Unpacking objects:  62% (43/69)
Unpacking objects: 100% (69/69), done.

master$ git pull
From github.com:...
   0246acdad6..d9ca9258b1  master                -> origin/master
 * [new tag]               rel-5.81.3553         -> rel-5.81.3553
 * [new tag]               rel-5.81.3554         -> rel-5.81.3554
Updating 0f95d6771f..d9ca9258b1
Fast-forward
... Actually pulling list of files
```

It is extremely frustrating and I see no explanation for it. 
Colleagues using the same network and same system and git version do not have this problem.

I am using

```
git version 2.11.0.windows.3
```

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: I haven't used git-bash, but are you sure that your local copy is not up to date with origin? It looks like there's nothing to pull, then a new commit is put on origin/master and your next pull sees it and pulls it.

Comment: I git pull when I know there is something to pull and these commands are issued conscutively with milliseconds difference

Comment: I recommend avoiding `git pull` anyway (run `git fetch`, then choose `git merge` or `git rebase` once `git fetch` finishes, where you now have the option of *looking at what you brought in* first)—but this should not be happening. It might be interesting to see if `git fetch` fails similarly.

Comment: Agree with @torek about fetching and merging/rebaseing separately. Take a look at http://www.hoonzis.com/git-stops-after-unpacking-objects-or/ if it fits your case.

Comment: Is it possible that other collaborators are pushing changes to other branches, between these pull.

Comment: No, 100% certain. Please assume that no one else is messing with it and that there are definitely stuff to pull.Also doesn't happen to anyone else. Tried updating git, gitbash, reinstalling.. etc. It's driving me catatonic